# How to display breadcrumbs in MACOS Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, console

I want to show the current directory breadcrumbs in terminal (MacOs) like the screen:

[image]

How can I do that?

Right now it's only a text...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Window -> Check "Path" under Working directory or document.

Path will be presented above working space as a part of window title.

I found as much. Hope that soothes your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is something called [zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH) with [oh my zsh framework](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh), [agnoster](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#agnoster) theme will give you the same experience in the pic.

You might also use a terminal called [hyper](https://hyper.is/)

Comment: thanks for pointing in that direction! TIL a lot from those 3 links! This should be the selected answer!